# tcsh if/then statement gives error

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to do a simple tcsh script to look for a folder, then navigate to it if it exists. The statement evaluates properly, but if it evaluates false, I get an error "then: then/endif not found". If it evaluates true, no problem. Where am I going wrong?

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set icmanagedir = ""
set workspace = `find -maxdepth 1 -name "*$user*" | sort -r | head -n1`
if ($icmanagedir != "" && $workspace != "") then
  setenv WORKSPACE_DIR `readlink -f $workspace`
  echo "Navigating to workspace" $WORKSPACE_DIR
  cd $WORKSPACE_DIR
endif
```

($icmanagedir is initialized elswehere, but I get the error regardless of which variable is empty)

Comment: It would be good to provide a [mcve], so people can reproduce the problem. That being that, I would guess that adding quotes around the `$icmanagedir` and `$workspace` will fix your problem: `if ("$icmanagedir" != "" && "$workspace" != "") then`. Also try adding a space after the `(` and before the `)`; some tcsh versions are finicky about that (and one reason you usually don't want to write programs in tcsh).

Comment: Adding the quotes around the variables and the spaces around the parentheses didn't help. If I put the code (updated) by itself in a script, I still get the error.

Comment: Hm, your example runs fine for me (the `if` is never entered as `icmanagedir` is always `""`). You're missing the closing backtick in the `setenv WORKSPACE_DIR ..` line btw. Copy/paste error?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Very strange... I expect it to never enter the if, and it doesn't, but I'm not sure why the heck it's giving me an error... What OS/tcsh version are you using? I think we have an old version since it doesn't support the '$( )' syntax...

Comment: No tcsh version supports the `$()` syntax; that only works in the Bourne shell. I use tcsh 6.20.00 on Linux. You can also try running it with `-x` to see some debug output, that might be helpful (`tcsh -x script.tcsh`).

Comment: Ah my mistake. I'm on 6.17. I ran it with -x but its not much help. It shows how the if statement evaluates: `if ( !=   &&   !=  ) then` but I still get an error

Comment: Turns out the problem is that I need an empty line at the end of the script... No idea why

Comment: Hah, I know what the problem is with that. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `tcsh` **needs** to have every line end in a newline, *including* the last line; it uses the newline as the "line termination character", and if it's missing it errors out.

You can use a hex editor/viewer to check if the file ends with a newline:

```
$ hexdump -C x.tcsh                                                  i:arch:21:49
00000000  69 66 20 28 22 78 22 20  3d 20 22 78 22 29 20 74  |if ("x" = "x") t|
00000010  68 65 6e 0a 09 65 63 68  6f 20 78 0a 65 6e 64 69  |hen..echo x.endi|
00000020  66                                                |f|
```

Here the last character if `f` (0x66), not a newline. A correct file has 0x0a as the last character (represented by a `.`):

```
$ hexdump -C x.tcsh    
00000000  69 66 20 28 22 78 22 20  3d 20 22 78 22 29 20 74  |if ("x" = "x") t|
00000010  68 65 6e 0a 09 65 63 68  6f 20 78 0a 65 6e 64 69  |hen..echo x.endi|
00000020  66 0a                                             |f.|
```

Ending the last line in a file with a newline is a common UNIX idiom, and some shell tools expect this. See [What's the point in adding a new line to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743/33645) for some more info on this.

Most UNIX editors (such as Vim, Nano, Emacs, etc.) should do this by default, but some editors or IDEs *don't* do this by default, but almost all editors have a setting through which this can be enabled.

The best solution is to enable this setting in your editor. If you can't do this then adding a blank line at the end also solves your problem.